# C++ Qt xml schema validation возврат ошибок в зависимости от проверки схемы на свой список ошибок

Tags: c++, qt

Привет всем. Работаю с Xml Schema, есть вопрос по поводу возврата ошибок при валидации схемы xsd с документом xml. К примеру у нас есть валидная схема xsd составленная по xml документу и есть сам валидный xml документ. К примеру мы нарочно делаем ошибку выхода за границу диапазона какого либо элемента в xml файле и проверяем его по схеме. По умолчанию ошибку выдает так:  Error XSDError in file (путь к файлу) (строка с ошибкой) (колонка с ошибкой) (текст ошибки) вот пример: content of element sia does not match its type defenition:  Signed integer content does not match the maxInclusive facet. Мне нужно возвратить код ошибки на примере любой доступной ошибки пример: мы получили эту же ошибку делаем (retrurn 34) взависимости от контекст ошибки и этот код ошибки выдает уже наш текст по русски (Элемент sia не соответствует допустимому значению). Проблема в том, как мне правильно реализовать все это? Как мне отследить любую ошибку в документе xml которую сделает пользователь и предусмотреть вывод ее кода ошибки и ошибки на русском? Буду очень благодарен если кто выложит тестовый пример. Смотрел на messageHandler, qInstallMessageHandler.

Comment: Вроде не первый день на сайте, а с форматированием сообщения ужас!

Comment: С мобильного пишу.

Comment: Поставьте приложение *Stack Exchange*, там всё достаточно удобно можно форматировать. Есть и под *Android*, и под *iOS*.

Comment: Спасибо, щас скачаю.